# Передача данных в контроллерах используя TabBar

Tags: ios, swift

есть два контроллера 1 и 2, мне нужно передать переменную из 1 в 2, я не могу этого сделать делегатом или segue, так как не за что зацепиться, как мне это сделать в TabBar'е?
[image: ![58%20PM|690x351](upload://nSmds8D2n8H5unWA6gsppSuNxsd.png)]

Примерно так в user2 дать значение из user1
ProfileEmployeeViewController - первый элемент в таббаре
MoreViewController - последний элемент в таббаре

```
1 - class ProfileEmployeeViewController: UIViewController {

    var user1: User?
 }

2 -  class MoreViewController: UIViewController {

    var user2: User? 
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        user1 = user2
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

1) получаем все контроллеры вашего таба:

```
let сontrollers = tabBarController?.viewControllers
```

2) Выбираем нужный контроллер:

```
let moreVC = controllers?.first { $0 is MoreViewController } as! MoreViewController
```

3) Обновляем проперти:

```
moreVC.user2 = user1
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про паттерны. Очевидный и  простой способ передачи небольших данных это использовать Singleton(одиночка). Есть куча простых примеров его использования в интернете на SWIFT